# How to create a nested route structure using separate routing.module.ts files per sub module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-router

I have an app that has a routing structure as follows

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'users/:userId/product/:productId',
    component: AppComponent,
    data: { animation: 'app' },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'grouping',
        component: GroupingComponent,
        children: [
        {
            path: 'overview',
            component: OverviewComponent,
            data: { animation: 'overview' }
        },
        {
            path: 'configuration',
            component: GroupConfigurationComponent,
            data: { animation: 'configuration' }
        }
      ]
     }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'grouping',
    redirectTo: 'users/:userId/product/:productId/grouping/overview',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

I have a router outlet nested within the main router outlet.  It displays the child routes of the grouping component.

How do I create this nested route structure using separate routing.module.ts files per sub module? (I have a GroupingModule

Comment: Please dont use angularX-somethig tags, just refer to the framework as angular

Comment: @Jota.Toledo There's no such rule, because tag descriptions should always be kept in mind. There are still `angular-*` tags that refer to AngularJS. angular5 tag wasn't relevant, while angular4-router was; angular-router is low profile and isn't specific enough which router it refers to (*service* word in the description suggests that it even could be AngularJS tag).

Comment: “Angular“ should strictly be used for the angular framework, and “angularjs“ for the previous. Sadly its currently not the case, but it doesnt mean that we should encourage angular2-*,angular4-* or angular5-* tags, as it makes no sense IMO to make a tag version specific, that info should be supplied in the question itself. I agree with your point, some descriptions should be improved.

Answer (score 0):

i'll post my example:

app routing

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':type/firstPage.html',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: ':type/firstPage-1' // for my redirect
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)], 
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

a child routing file example

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { YourComponent } from './components/yourComponent.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':type/firstPage-1', // the route where i redirect first
    component: YourComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)], 
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class YourComponentRoutingModule { }
```

For modules, you will put your specific component routing.ts file into his module, and then you'll have to import this specific module inside app.module

hope this helped